# Есть ли быстрые клавиши для взятия кода в блок

Tags: visual-studio

Например, мне нужно из такого фрагмента

```
if (a == b) Console.WriteLine("Equals"); c = true;
```

Получить такой

```
if (a == b) { Console.WriteLine("Equals"); c = true; }
```

То есть я хочу выделить часть кода, нажать какую-то быструю комбинацию и получить фигурные скобки вокруг.

И обратная операция.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выделяете кусок кода, который вам нужно внести в фигурные скобки, и нажимаете **Shift + {**

Если не работает, то перейдите в
"Средства->Параметры->Текстовый редактор->С/С++->Дополнительно".

В конце будут 2 настройки:

1."Включение заключения в фигурные скобки".

2."Включение заключения в круглые скобки".

В обоих случаях ставим **true**

Comment: Для c# не нашёл такой настройки. Для C/C++ проверить не могу, не установлены. Ничего утверждать не могу, но Shift+[ (или {) - это ввод символа, что просто заменяет выделение.

Comment: А какой версией VS вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Community 2022 (17.6.5)

Comment: Да, к сожалению почему-то на C#/F# в VS 2022 не добавили данную опцию.
Попробуйте установить расширение Auto Surround. Оно обладает таким же функционалом и должно работать в C# (*https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=reduckted.AutoSurround*)

Comment: Крайний вариант найти, либо написать свой сниппет.

Comment: Супер! Auto Surround работает, спасибо! А есть ли обратная операция? Удалить скобки вокруг курсора?

Comment: Насчёт этого уже не могу ничего вам сказать. Но по идее должна работать и обратная операция.